# Get the name of a method stored in a variable

Tags: javascript, inheritance, methods

I have some trouble with getting the name of a method stored in a variable... Here is an exemple of what I want :

```
Function MyObject(){
    this.actualMethod = this.thatName;
}

MyObject.prototype.thatName = function(){}

MyObject.prototype.getActualMethodName = function(){
    return this.actualMethod.name; /* This doesn't work since the function itself is anonymous, so this.actualMethod.name doesn't work... I want it to return "thatName" */
}
```

I tried to navigate through the prototype with my console, in vain... Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: What's the problem? Just `return this.actualMethod;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to name the function:

```
MyObject.prototype.thatName = function thatName() {};
```

Or, as you mentioned, you can find its name in the prototype (but I wouldn't suggest you to do it):

```
for (var key in MyObject.prototype) {
  if (MyObject.prototype[key] === this.actualMethod) {
    return key;
  }
}
```

But why do you need this? Maybe there could be a better solution.

Comment: Is naming the function (solution 1) a good practice ? I never saw this before... But the second solution seems to work =) ! I didn't knew it was possible to just iterate like this... It seems so simple !

Comment: I work on a project involving manipulating squares on canvas. 
"Onmousedown", I choose a method to call ("move", "resize"...) with the position of the mouse beside the square. 
"Onmousemove", the chosen method is called (if the mouse is still down), so I need to store it in a variable ("this.actualMethod") in order to call it onmousemove. 
"Onmouseup", I want to call a callback function. I have an array of functions that looks like this : {'move':function(){/*dostuff*/},'resize':function{/*otherstuff*/}}. The key of each function is the chosen function name, so I need to get it.

Comment: Well, if you need the name for some reason, it's a good practice. But it doesn't work in IE.

But couldn't you just return the actual function, as @hindmost suggested, and then just call it?